# Empty set when reading resource files with extension in java

Tags: java

I am using a well known code lines to get resource files from resource folder in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*");

Set<String> resources = new Reflections("", new ResourcesScanner()).getResources(pattern);

// ...
```

It work's like a charm. I get all the files in directory, but when I use a following pattern, the set is empty, why?

```
// etc.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".txt");
```

Comment: Wouldn't the pattern be .*?\.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hoipolloi suggested in the comments, the solution is to use the following pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*.txt");
```